# "Windows cannot find" popup message on login

Tags: windows-xp, login

I am getting a popup message soon after I sign into Windows which says:

> "Windows cannot find "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\admin\fgnjhk.exe".Make sure
>   you typed the name correctly , and
>   then try again. to search for a file
>   ,click the start button , and then
>   click search.

I tried to find this file , but could not. I am not sure if this is because of a virus .

How can I stop this popup?

Comment: Have you run your virus-scanner?  Which one is it?

Answer (score 4):

1. download and run **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)**, disable or remove the entry for "fgnjhk.exe" (this will take care of the error message).
2. download, install, update and run a quick scan with **[MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)**, remove infections.
3. update your antivirus software and run a complete system scan.

Comment: +1 It looks like a virus created a startup entry to its exe which must have been deleted by the anti virus software on your PC. However the AV did not delete the startup entry.

Comment: yep, that's the most likely explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much Molly for the reply , I am now able to get rid of that error message . However I am now getting the My computer window automatically soon after signing to windows :( . I again tried to check this in Autorun as u suggested , but I did not find  this in the list ( or I may have missed this in the list ) .

Please please suggest and advice .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look over the startup items so that u can disable this search item if any.

Install a autorun eater by which this sort of virus or trojans acn be removed.